Story revolves around A little girl, her step mother, her dad, her dad's friend
I saw a hollywood movie in television in 2009 but I did not see the full movie and I can't remenber the movies' name. 
The plot revolves around a teenage girl, her step mom, her Dad, her dad's Friend.
The girl was going with her mom and dad in car a night when she was a little girl and they met with an accident an in that accident her mom died.
Her father married another woman with her permission. Her Father and her father's friend is working together to invent some flying object (I can't remember properly). 
The teenage girl misses her mom. She remembers the time with her mom when she was little and she plays swing with her mom. She also remembers and see the table drawer in which she gives place for newly born chicks or ducks. 
One day while she was bathing she came out from the bathing room frightened about something (I don't know why because I can't remember) that time her father's friend (he has long hair I think) saw her with out clothes. 
She feels bad for her nude presence in front of her father's friend. Her step mom consoles her. 
Here after I did not see the movie. I want to know the movie.

I believe you're looking for the 1996 film Fly Away Home.
It does feature a car accident, a long haired friend and step mum. She also has an incident with the shower in which the dad's friend see's her by accident.

Amy is only 13 years old when her mother is killed in an auto wreck in New Zealand. She goes to Canada to live with her father, an eccentric inventor whom she barely knows. Amy is miserable in her new life...that is until she discovers a nest of goose eggs that were abandoned when developers began tearing up a local forest. 
The eggs hatch and Amy becomes "Mama Goose". The young birds must fly south for the winter, but who will lead them there? 

Here's the trailer:



